# Convergence and Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

Prove that if $(f_n)$ is a sequence of nonnegative, measurable functions on $[a,b]$ such that $lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b f_n(x)dx=0$, then $(f_n)$ converges to $0$ in measure. Show by example that we cannot replace the conclusion with the assertion that $(f_n)$ converges to $0$ almost everywhere.

I don't really know how to go about proving this. I know that convergence almost everywhere implies convergence in measure and that if a sequence converges in measure then there exists a subsequence that converges almost everywhere but I haven't done a lot with convergence in measure.

Comment: For an counterexample take an example with a 'running maximum', that is $f_{n,k}(x) = 1_{[k/,(k+1)/n]}(x)$.

Comment: So I understand the example that shows this but without using Markovs inequality where should I start in proving the theorem?

Answer (score 2):

Use Markov's inequality namely,
$$
\mu(|f_n|>\varepsilon)\leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_a^b f_n(x)\, dx.
$$

Comment: So I don't have Markov's inequality at my disposal. Some theorems I have are The Dominated Convergence Theorem, Egorov's Theorem, Almost everywhere implies in measure, and Riesz's theorem which I stated above.

Comment: And you have outed yourself as a statistician :). +1

Comment: @ICanMakeYouHateME It is not too hard  to prove the inequality from scratch in your particular case.